NameError: variable not defiend even though its defiend
The first code block outputs:

"NameError: name 'timefloat' is not defined"

while the other works as intended. Why is that?
Code Block 1: raises ERROR
def main():
    time = input("Whats the time? ")
    convert(time)
    print(timefloat)


def convert(hour):
    (h, m) = hour.split(":")
    timefloat = float(h) + float(m) / 60
    return timefloat


main()

Code Block 2: Works correctly
def main():
    time = input("Whats the time? ")
    newtime = convert(time)
    print(newtime)


def convert(hour):
    (h, m) = hour.split(":")
    return(float(h) + float(m) / 60)


main()


To my very limited knowledge "timefloat" looks defined, and these two codes should return the same result.

Mandatory link to Ned Batchelder

In the first example, timefloat is a local variable inside the convert() function.  It is not visible anywhere else.

In the first example, you called the convert() function but you did not assign its returned value to a variable:
convert(time)

In the second example, you did assign the returned value to a variable:
newtime = convert(time)

That is the difference.

In python(and in most programming languages), there is a concept known as scope of a variable. It means in which code block a variable is accessible. That's what happening with your "Code Block 1".
timefloat variable is defined in convert() function but not in main() function.
convert() function returns the value stored in timefloat variable, but in main function there isn't any variable to catch and save convert() functions result that's returned. A simple analogy would be "You throw a ball to your friend but he doesnt catch it`.
Thats the reason why your "Code Block 2" works. It catches and save the result of convert() function into a variable "newtime" and that variable is later used inside main() function.
I also suggest you to check NameError: name 'recPower' is not defined question.

Thanks for answer! Intuitively I still read the two codes alike, but I havent understood the concept of score just yet, obviously.

my answer is an in detail explanation to the answer of @John Gordon.

@user27764244, refer w3school site for more detials on scope

You can not use a variable defined in one of the subroutines since it is not defined in the other

This is a variable scope issue, the code below should works as you want
timefloat = 0

def main():
    global timefloat
    time = input("Whats the time? ")
    convert(time)
    print(timefloat)


def convert(hour):
    global timefloat
    (h, m) = hour.split(":")
    timefloat = float(h) + float(m) / 60
    return timefloat


main()


Thanks for example to code block 1. I obviously haven't understood scope properly yet.
